# Text content does not match server-rendered HTML when using double quotations inside template literal in jsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

JSX

```
<div>
  <style>{`
    p::before {
      content: "";
    }
  `}</style>
  <p>Hello World.</p>
</div>
```

Console

[image]

Sandbox

https://codesandbox.io/s/text-content-does-not-match-forked-poqkij?file=/pages/index.js:53-181